# Why cy.task gives null instead of file reading, where mistake in code?

Tags: cypress

I use cy.task in order to read data from txt file with name alertText.txt.
But I receive AssertionError:"object tested must be an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but null given". I can't understand where I do mistake.

in my test file there is following code:

```
it.only('Alert with cy.task',()=>{            
           cy.task('readFileMaybe', 'alertText.txt').then((textOrNull) => { 
            expect(textOrNull).to.contains('Hello');             
            })
```

in cypress.config.js following code:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = defineConfig({  
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        readFileMaybe(alertText) {
          if (fs.existsSync(alertText)) {
            return fs.readFileSync(alertText, 'utf8')
          }

          return null
        },
      })
    },
  },
})
```

Txt file alertText.txt is existing and actually I can read it with below following command

```
cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/test1.txt').should('contain', 'Testersdock').
```

But I have a task to read file with cy.task. Could you please help find mistake? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Task file paths are always relative to the project root, because it runs in the node process (the process started by `npx cypress open`) and that starts up from the project root.

So please add full path from root, or pass in correct path

```js
readFileMaybe(alertText) {
  const filePath = `./cypress/fixtures/${alertText}`
  return fs.existsSync(filePath) ? fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8') : null;
}
```